# How to properly filter array (while retaining original data aswell)

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, svelte-3

I have a bit of an issue, that i dont know how to properly solve.

I have an array that i use to fill my DataTable with, when the value is added to array, it is also reflected in the table. And adding and removing works very well. How ever i want to search array when user enters some data to search field, and if user enters data and presses "Search" it works, however i want that search responds to input change, so every time that user presses some letter that it starts the filter.

```
 let people = [
{ name: 'Jack', lastName: 'London', age: 25, id: 1 },
{ name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 33, id: 2 },
{ name: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Mith', age: 22, id: 3 },
  ];



 function sortArray(string) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      if (people[i].string == string) arr.push(people[i]);
    }
    return (people = [...arr]);
  }
```

Now things are bit complicated, let say users enters letter S in to the search box, function filters array, (and now there is nothing in array), so i need to hold value of origina array somewhere as a refrence

I did try to filter it,

```
function filter(arr, string) {
var regex = new RegExp('.*' + string + '.*');
return arr.filter(function (el) {
  return regex.exec(el.name);
});
```

}

but had no luck either.

I am using Svelte, IBM Carbon datatable, (though i dont think that changes anything).

I might even get this somehow to work, but i think it would be highly inficient, so if anyone has solution i would be very thankful.

Also what are the costs (performance wise) when we copy array using spread operator, with moderate amount of data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of displaying/modifying your data you may want to display your search result data. You can still add/edit/delete your original data as you are doing but only display items in the data table that match the search query or show all items if the search query is empty.

You can use any function that returns an array of objects as the value for rows when using IBM Carbon DataTable, a simple example might look like this:

```
<script>
 import { DataTable } from "carbon-components-svelte";
 let  value = "";
 let people = [
    { name: 'Jack', lastName: 'London', age: 25, id: 1 },
    { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 33, id: 2 },
    { name: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Mith', age: 22, id: 3 }
 ];

 function search(items, query) {
    if (!query) {
        return items
    }
    const results = items.filter(item => {
        // Replace with whatever filter method you like
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || item.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    })
    return results
}
</script>

<label for="search">
  <input id="search" bind:value />
</label>
<!-- The rows value calls a function that returns an array after filtering it, this will be called on every change to the query -->
<DataTable
  headers={[{ key: 'name', value: 'First name' }, { key: 'lastName', value: 'Last name' }, { key: 'age', value: 'Age' }, { key: 'id', value: 'Id' }]}
  rows={search(people, value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Filtering/performance:**

When it comes to filtering, `array.filter` has never let me down performance wise and I had cases where I filter up to 10.000 items without you even noticing it.
There is also no way you could improve your search by using the subset of the last search.
The user can backspace or remove the filter all together, so filtering on the original subset is basically a must.

What is mostly the biggest problem when it comes to performance, is the visualization.
If you have a table that visualizes all records at once, they all have to be rendered, which is costly.
So components who support paging for example, raise your performance.
So what it comes to, `array.filter` will not be your bottleneck.

**Logic (side remark):**

Your filter has at least 1 issue.
you use .* => that means you will never be able to filter on the first or last letter of the name, .? solves this.

**Sample:**

I added the most marginal of samples (based on your data) to do a quick filter on the data. Just for reference sake. It's all inline, no fancy stuff.

```js
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <ul id="output">
    </ul>
  </body>
  <script>
   let people = [
    { name: 'Jack', lastName: 'London', age: 25, id: 1 },
    { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 33, id: 2 },
    { name: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Mith', age: 22, id: 3 }
   ];
   
   function filter(arr, string) {
     var regex = new RegExp('.?' + string + '.?');
     return arr.filter(function (el) {
       return regex.exec(el.name);
     });
   };
   
   const inp = document.getElementById("input");
   const outp = document.getElementById("output");
   
   inp.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
     render();
   });
   
   function render(){
     var result = filter(people, inp.value);
     outp.innerHTML = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
       var node = document.createElement("li");
       node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].name));
       outp.appendChild(node);
     }
     console.log(result);
   };
  </script>
</html>
```